# Java: How to get Strings from JcomboBox

Tags: java, jdbc, actionlistener, jcombobox

I've looked at similar questions but both examples and answers were too complicated for me to understand.

I'm working on project and basically need to be able to select items from combobox menu so i can run queries in JDBC. I got help on JDBC part.

QUESTION: I'm confused weather to use ActionListener, ItemStateChanged or both!

And also what part of code do i need to put in the above methods.

Thank you for help`

```
    package userProfile;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

public class Database extends GUI implements ActionListener   {

        JFrame frame;
        JButton search;
        JComboBox fromLoc, toLoc, fromDate, fromTime;
        JLabel fromLabel, toLabel, fromDateLabel, fromTimeLabel;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        Connection link;
        ResultSet rs = null;

    public  Database() {

        frame = new JFrame("Make a Reservation");
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);     

        //Arrival date/time comboBoxes and labels
        fromDateLabel = new JLabel("Departure Date");
        fromDateLabel.setBounds(50,230,100,30);
        fromDate = new JComboBox(new String[]{"12/15/2015", 
                  "12/21/2015", "12/21/2015", "12/24/2015"});
        fromDate.addActionListener(this);
        fromDate.setBounds(50,200,100,30);

        fromTimeLabel = new JLabel("Departure Time");
        fromTimeLabel.setBounds(160,230,100,30);
        fromTime = new JComboBox(new String[]{"13:00", 
                  "15:00", "15:30", "08:00"});
        fromTime.addActionListener(this);
        fromTime.setBounds(160,200,100,30);

        //Departure label and comboBox
        fromLabel = new JLabel("Departure");
        fromLabel.setBounds(50,300,100,30);
        fromLoc = new JComboBox(new String[]{"Atlanta", 
                  "Charleston", "New York", "Los Angeles", 

"Orlando", "San Francisco"});
        fromLoc.addActionListener(this);
        fromLoc.setBounds(50,270,100,30);

        toLabel = new JLabel("Arrival");
        toLabel.setBounds(160,300,100,30);
        toLoc = new JComboBox(new String[]{"Atlanta", 
                  "Charleston", "New York", "Los Angeles", "Orlando", "San Francisco"});
        toLoc.addActionListener(this);
        toLoc.setBounds(160,270,100,30);

        search = new JButton("Ok");
        search.addActionListener(this);
        search.setBounds(270,270,100,30);
        //adding the buttons in frame
        frame.getContentPane().add(fromDateLabel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(fromDate);
        frame.getContentPane().add(fromTimeLabel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(fromTime);
        frame.getContentPane().add(fromLabel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(fromLoc);
        frame.getContentPane().add(toLabel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(toLoc);
        frame.getContentPane().add(search);

        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setVisible(true);


        StateChange state = new StateChange();

          try {
                // Driver for mysql
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                 // connection link obj
                 link = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world", "root", "root");   
                 // query statement obj
                 ps = link.prepareStatement("select * from flights where from_date = ? and from_loc = ? and to_loc = ?");

                 ps.setString(1, fromD);
                 ps.setString(2, fromL);
                 ps.setString(3, toL);

                 rs = ps.executeQuery();

                 while (rs.next()) {


                }

                } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                    System.out.println("An error occurred.Maybe user/password is invalid");
                    sqle.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException cfne) {
                    cfne.printStackTrace();
                }

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

        private class StateChange implements ItemListener {

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
          //  String toLoc = (String)e.getItem();
           // System.out.println(s);

        // here i just used strings to get content from comboBox
                String fromL = fromLoc.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String fromD = fromDate.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String toL = toLoc.getSelectedItem().toString();

    }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to override the actionPerformed() method and here is the method to get the text of selected option

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JComboBox fromL = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
    String fromL = (String) fromLoc.getSelectedItem();

    // do whatever you want with the values
    ...
  }
```

Now you got the texts selected from the corresponding comboboxes now you can use the texts. Refer section : **Handling Events on a Combo Box** in the link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html
if you still have any doubt.